# Representation theory in the binary tetrahedral group

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose that $G$ be the finite group $G = {±1, ±i, ±j, ±k, \frac{1}{2} (\pm 1 \pm i \pm j \pm k)}$ of order $24$ with group
structure given by multiplication of quaternions.

(Recall that the algebra $\mathbb{H}$ of quaternions
is the $4$-dimensional division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis ${1, i, j, k}$ and product determined by
$i^2 = j^2
 = k^2
 = ijk = −1.)$ 
 I find all the conjugacy class representatives for $G$ and the character table of $G$

The questin is (if The algebra $\mathbb{H}$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^2$
 via the representation

$1\mapsto \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\\ \end{array} \right), i\mapsto \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0& 1 \\ 1 & 0\\ \end{array} \right), j\mapsto \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0& i \\ i & 0\\ \end{array} \right), k\mapsto \left( \begin{array}{cc} i& 0 \\ 0 & i\\ \end{array} \right)$.

Write $V$ for the corresponding degree $2$ representation of ${G}$. Show that for $U$ and $W$
complex representations of $\mathbb{G}$, we have

$dim Hom_{\mathbb{C}G}(U, V \otimes W) = dim Hom_{\mathbb{C}G}(W, V \otimes U).$

Comment: Please, are there any help

Comment: There are too many grammatical mistakes in your question.  Currently, I am quite confused by what you are saying and not certain what you are asking.  Can you try to fix them?  Maybe restate your question in your native tongue, and somebody who speaks the language can help translate.

Comment: I hope know the question is clear to you

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb H$ is a (right) 2D complex vector space, and $\Bbb H$ acts on itself (via left multiplication) as linear transformations, so we get a representation $\Bbb H\to M_2(\Bbb C)$. In this way we get a 2D complex rep of the 24-cell.